# Java - Creating an RPG dialog

Tags: java, swing, graphics, text

So this may seem strange, but I am trying to create a very basic game that works somewhat like what an older RPG game may have as the interface (think choosing attacks from a list (ex: Pokemon)).

Right now I have a class that extends JFrame, and it contains private variables of three panels: one for displaying the sprites at the top 75% of the screen, and the other two are the ones I wish to display text on (one for announcements like, "CRITICAL HIT" and the other for the selectable choices). The second of the text boxes would only be visible sometimes, but that is irrelevant.

Can anybody start me off or lend me a hand? I am finding many way but none that seem to work for my needs.

Edit: My game is laid out and the sprite panel works exactly as it should, as much as it may sound like it, I am not rushing into anything blindly. I have the game working except for displaying the dialogs in an effective way.

EDIT 2: Ok maybe I am being unclear, my basic concern is finding the best Java component to draw strings to the bottom panels. The strings will be changing regularly, so some methods that I have tried such as the Graphics drawString() are not very effective.

Thank you,
roflha

Comment: Are you clear on which will be your steps to take in order to get your game complete? I advise you to write down all your ideas about this game, make a few -or a lot- sketches or story boards and then dig into coding

Comment: I have absolutely everything else laid out, it is not even a big game, maybe 4 or 5 options and that's it, I just need to know this one detail.

Comment: A little too vague to get good answers. You need to have some ideas and ask more specific questions. Like "How do I get a JPanel to occupy 75% of a JFrame?"

Comment: I wasn't actually asking that part. That part is working fine along with animated sprites.

Comment: "The strings will be changing regularly, so some methods that I have tried such as the Graphics drawString() are not very effective."  That makes no sense if the UI is being painted regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your original question statement lacks any actual cohesive question, other than "Can anybody start me off or lend me a hand?" which makes it rather hard to figure out what you really need.  I discerned that what you want help from us about is displaying dialogues that popup to the user when some event happens.  If you don't care too much about special effects, there are three easy ways to do this:

1) Simply have sprites for your messages, and set them to visible as needed.  If you have a limited number of important messages, this makes it easy to control the visibility/flashiness of the message.

2) JTextArea allows you to simply print some text to a box.  It is useful if you have a wordy console or messages that can't simply be a few images.  You would just have a JTextArea in your panel, and update it as needed:

```
JTextArea messageBox;
messagePanel.add(messageBox);

//displays a message
messageBox.setText("CRITICAL HIT!!!");
```

But the user may not notice when the text changes, since it changes instantly.  Whether you want to flash the text, or display some animation on top of the text area is up to you.

3) If you want a more intrusive message, you can actually have a popup dialogue where the user would have to click "OK" to continue.  This is relatively easy to do, and you can even put custom icons for the message:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,
    "You got a critical hit!!!", 
    "Critical Hit",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
    criticalHitIcon);
```